# Технический вопрос по Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Здравствуйте. При работе с фреймворком Code Igniter у меня возникла проблема, иногда при обновлении страницы, страница не загружается, т.е. после обновления загружается попросту пустая страница. Стоит обновить еще раз - страница загружается как нужно, с отображением контента. Не подскажете, как исправить это?

Comment: смотрите лог web сервера.

Comment: Где смотреть? У меня денвер, в логах CI пусто.

Comment: в логах апача. (не представляю где там это у денвера, но точно должно быть)

---
и это господа, запомните - денвер это всего-лишь способ дистрибутива windows apache mysql php, не надо говорить "у меня сервер денвер" это реально глупо выглядит.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2hi5pb Вот что в логе

Comment: а всякие display_errors и прочее включены ? в смысле пройдите обычные шаги по дебагу php.